# Android apps button size

Tags: android

am an upcoming android developer. I have my app in eclipse running on 2.2 android platform and the only thing remaining is adding  fancy buttons to it. I have designed some buttons using photoshop but my main problem is to get the right dimensions (width, height and pixels) for my button so that they can fit properly on the screen. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear what exactly you are asking for here *(hence the negative question score already I guess)*. Please edit your question to make it more clear, e.g. note what you tried/what dimensions you set and why this doesn't work for you. Maybe attach a screenshot if relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is play with your .xml file. You have to adjust your Buttons's properties like width and height and that will do.

Start playing with this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50sp"
        android:width="100sp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_image"
        android:text="I'm a button" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I recommend you this reading:
[Android Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: I think he's asking about image buttons. In that case, you need to add an android:background="@drawable/my_image" to the button definition, and I'm not sure the height and width is the best way to select the size. Probably better to use the drawable-ldpi, etc. folders

Comment: You're right, I have the background property. I am concerned about what you tell of height and width, but I think this is still the most accurate and easy option for him as a beginner

Comment: @ArcDare, I'm just saying resizing an image is usually not great and produces blurry images. The good practice in Android is to have multiple images in specific drawable folders to support various screen resolutions: see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

lucky for you, android sdk comes with a tool that allows you to adjust which parts of your image can be stretched, and which shouldn't be (as i'm thinking that's what you're worrying about). it's called 9-patch, and you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)